# Which coefficient is correct for assessing effect size of a regression interaction, standardized or unstandardized?

Tags: interaction, regression-coefficients, effect-size, standardization

My team is conducting a healthcare regression analysis and is interested in both the p-value and the magnitude of an interaction coefficient (i.e., effect size). For our project we want p-value < .01 and an effect size of at least 5% to determine if the interaction is practically significant.

Using the `mtcars` dataset for illustration, when running a regression of `mpg` on both the unstandardized and standardized `disp`, `hp`, and `disp*hp` variables, the R-squared and p-values are identical, however the coefficients are different.

Which interaction term coefficient is the "correct" one to use for assessing effect size?

```
attach(mtcars)  
summary(lm(mpg ~ disp + hp + disp*hp))
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + hp + disp * hp)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5153 -1.6315 -0.6346  0.9038  5.7030 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  3.967e+01  2.914e+00  13.614 7.18e-14 ***
disp        -7.337e-02  1.439e-02  -5.100 2.11e-05 ***
hp          -9.789e-02  2.474e-02  -3.956 0.000473 ***
disp:hp      2.900e-04  8.694e-05   3.336 0.002407 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.692 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8198,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8005 
F-statistic: 42.48 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 1.499e-10
  
disp_std = scale(disp)
hp_std = scale(hp)
disp_hp_std = scale(disp*hp)
summary(lm(mpg ~ disp_std + hp_std + disp_hp_std))
Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp_std + hp_std + disp_hp_std)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.5153 -1.6315 -0.6346  0.9038  5.7030 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  20.0906     0.4758  42.223  < 2e-16 ***
disp_std     -9.0938     1.7831  -5.100 2.11e-05 ***
hp_std       -6.7119     1.6966  -3.956 0.000473 ***
disp_hp_std   9.9187     2.9731   3.336 0.002407 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.692 on 28 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8198,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.8005 
F-statistic: 42.48 on 3 and 28 DF,  p-value: 1.499e-10
```

Answer (score 1):

The choice of coefficient should depend on business needs and your desired interpretation, no? In your example, a unit increase in `disp*hp` is associated with a 0.0003 unit increase in `mpg`. For practical significance, would this be at least a 5% increase over the baseline mean of `mpg`? In the standardized case, a $\frac{1}{33333}$ increase in standard deviation of `disp_hp_std` yields the same unit increase in `mpg`.